# Count consecutive 0 in SQL

Tags: mysql

I try to work out a calculation using SQL.

My database has the first 3 columns below and I need to work out the fourth:

```
Month |Name |Monthly Premium Paid |Number of consecutive months paid
Jan 2010 | Bob | Y | 1
Feb 2010 | Bob | Y | 2
Mar 2010 | Bob | N | 0
Apr 2010 | Bob | Y | 1
May 2010 | Bob | Y | 2
Jul 2010 | Bob | N | 0
```

Comment: can you try to explain a biiit more?

Comment: It would be great to have some DDL.

Comment: Sorry. My title is little bit confused. Actually it is count the flag of 'Y' in fourth column.

Comment: The column 'Number of consecutive months paid' is what we expect to show

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

```
select month, name, premiun_paid,
    @row_number:=CASE
        WHEN premiun_paid = 'Y' THEN @row_number + 1
        ELSE 0 
        END consecutive_month
from table,(select @row_number:=0)r
```

Ref: http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-row_number/

**Schema (MySQL v5.7)**

```
create table fiddle(month text,name text,
                    premium text,number int);

insert into fiddle values('Jan','Bob','Y',0),
                         ('Feb','Bob','Y',0),
                         ('Mar','Bob','N',0),
                         ('Apr','Bob','Y',0),
                         ('May','Bob','Y',0),
                         ('June','Bob','N',0),
                         ('Jul','Bob','Y',0),
                         ('Aug','Bob','Y',0),
                         ('Sep','Bob','Y',0);
```

---

**Query #1**

```
select month, name, premium,
    @row_number:=CASE
        WHEN premium='Y' THEN @row_number + 1
        ELSE 0 
        END as consecutive_months 
from fiddle,(select @row_number:=0)r;

| month | name | premium | consecutive_months |
| ----- | ---- | ------- | ------------------ |
| Jan   | Bob  | Y       | 1                  |
| Feb   | Bob  | Y       | 2                  |
| Mar   | Bob  | N       | 0                  |
| Apr   | Bob  | Y       | 1                  |
| May   | Bob  | Y       | 2                  |
| June  | Bob  | N       | 0                  |
| Jul   | Bob  | Y       | 1                  |
| Aug   | Bob  | Y       | 2                  |
| Sep   | Bob  | Y       | 3                  |
```

---

Comment: A fiddle for this. https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/hPH6vZMzNyGE9DLkXWocWh/0